# how to load two dimensional integer array from application.properties file into a java class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add this to application.properties file
my.list.of.strings={{1,2},{2,3}}
And load this value into Java class. How do I do this?
I have tried
@Value("#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}") 
private List myList;
but it didnot work...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a year ago by creating a config class.

**Config yaml:**

```yaml
my:
  servers:
    - dev.example.com
    - another.example.com
```

**Config class:**

```java
@Profile("servers")
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PackageConfig {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }

    public void setServers(List<String> servers) {
        this.servers = servers;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).